# Get py3status/i3status to allow clicks

Tags: python, window-managers

I have the right code/configuration or so it seems

~/.i3/py3status_screen/i3bar_click_events.py

```
self.actions = {
    "wireless eth1": {
        1: [external_command, 'nm-connection-editor'],
    },
}
```

/etc/i3status.conf

```
wireless eth1 {
    format_up = "W: (%quality at %essid) %ip"
    format_down = "W: down"
}
```

Is there something else I need to do?
And if I'm not clear on something, let me know, all I want to do is make it so that when I click on the W: part, my wifi network manager comes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed with you on IRC, click events were introduced in i3wm v4.6, just upgrade i3 :)

Comment: and for those that need packages for the new i3, I compiled a list.. https://docs.google.com/document/d/14sAe7Mxyqg38SrdnG8hV-cWieSGEtOh2UIDSAtLOZNw Just install these packages and you should be good, if you have any questions then see me(IotaSpencer) or Ultrabug in #py3status on freenode